# Font awesome spinner not spinning

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I have completed an installation of fontawesome in Nuxt with this fantastic link;

https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome

I have a spinner rendered as

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas','spinner']" />
```

The spinner does not spin, it is static.

I added fa-spin as

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas','spinner', 'spin']" />
```

This caused the error in the console `Could not find one or more icon(s) undefined`

Can anyone point me in the right direction, show me how to get my spinner spinning.

The relevant portion on the `nuxt.config.js`

```
    modules: [
        'nuxt-fontawesome'
],


//font-awesome
  fontawesome: {
    imports: [
        {
          set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
          icons: ['fas']
        },
    ],
  },

build: {
      config.resolve.alias['@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands$'] = '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/shakable.es.js'
      config.resolve.alias['@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid$'] = '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/shakable.es.js'
    }
```

In the component(**"../pages/index.vue"**) it is;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas','spinner','spin' ]" />
  </div>
</template>
```

As suggested by @Steve, i have created a Glitch workspace
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/d57a5054-b448-4a53-ad37-d9465b0cef8b

Comment: could you provide the main.js and the component code?

Comment: Did you register it as a nuxt plugin? If the source for the spin icon module requires client-side integration, you'll also need to disable ssr in the plugin configuration

Comment: No I did not register as a next plugin, I did not see any reference to it in the docs. Kindly point to it or illustrate with code so I get the idea

Comment: My bad, not plugin related. How did you import faSpin? Is it part of pro icons? If so, you'll need to import it. Would you be able to provide a live example on glitch.com?

Comment: @Steve Glitch workspace created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless times have changed, Font Awesome does not provide out-of-the-box tools to animate their font and graphic libraries. They simply provide the service of offering single-colored, vector-graphic libraries formatted for various needs: true-type fonts (TTF), scalable vector graphics (SVG), etc.

You'll need to do the animation work yourself. Fortunately, it's very short work with CSS plus you'll get to control the speed of your spinner spinning.

```
/* Define an animation behavior */
@keyframes spinner {
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
/* This is the class name given by the Font Awesome component when icon contains 'spinner' */
.fa-spinner {
  /* Apply 'spinner' keyframes looping once every second (1s)  */
  animation: spinner 1s linear infinite;
}
```

I've updated the Glitch workspace you created (very helpful) with the additional CSS lines above to animate. Adjust accordingly and good luck!

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I modified my code accordingly, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Font Awesome 5 has the class `fa-spin`

Comment: The answer by Emanoel Trevisol is the correct one. I don't why you would re invent the wheel with all that code when just `spin` will do the job.

Comment: I had to use this answer because spin is not cross-platform compatible.  Try adding the `fa-spin` class to the icons on this page in Windows and you will see they don't spin, but they do on a Mac: https://fontawesome.com/icons

Answer (score 35):

You can add the `spin` directive.

`<font-awesome-icon icon="spinner" spin />`

Docs: https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#basic

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="spinner" class="fa-spin" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Font Awesome v.5, Vue.js v.2 (with @vue/cli 3)

Comment: thanks. i'm using reactjs, this works for me: `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpinner} className="fa-spin" />`