# FontAwesome spinner won't spin in React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I created a React application with `npx create-react-app`.

Then following these instructions

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

I installed the Font Awesome dependences:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Then I changed the `App.js` to this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { FaSpinner } from 'react-icons/fa';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <FaSpinner icon="spinner" spin /> This is a test.
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But it only displays a spinner icon that is not spinning:

[image]

How do I get the spinner to spin?

## NOTE:

**Outside of React**, Font Awesome works fine without doing any extra work to animate the icons, e.g. this simple HTML code shows an animated icon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title>testspin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"
       aria-hidden="true"></i> 
This is a test
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do in order to get the React version to work this easily?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font awesome spinner not spinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225228/font-awesome-spinner-not-spinning)

Comment: FontAwsome is an icon library not an animation library. Use CSS transitions or an animation library like framer motion.

Comment: I've found all kinds of posts like that, but they are not about React in particular. Yeah, I've added the `fa-spin` class, etc. (`<FaSpinner icon="spinner" spin className="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" />`) but it's not working in React.

Comment: Well, I've used Font Awesome many times before outside of React and animations worked out-of-the-box with e.g. `<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>` and the instructions on the Font Awesome React page are to simply use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" spin />` but it doesn't spin.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default,  the spinner will not spin. But a simple way to trigger it to spin just like the logo of React after creating a new react app.
Add a **className** of spin to the icon and add a little css to trigger it spinning such like that below:

**App.js**

```
import react from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FaSpinner } from 'react-icons/fa';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <FaSpinner icon="spinner" className="spinner" /> This is a test.
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.spinner {
    animation: spin infinite 5s linear;

    /*You can increase or decrease the timer (5s) to 
     increase or decrease the speed of the spinner*/
  }

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Actually you just need to add the class `fa-spin`, no need to add any custom css, this is already included with React-Fontawesome for the class `fa-spin`. Here is an example from a project of mine:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { faCog, faFilePdf } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'


const MyComponent = () => {
  const [pdfCreatingState,setPdfCreatingState] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = ev => {
      setPdfCreatingState(true);
      setTimeout(() => generatePDFDocument(docData,docName));
  }

  const generatePDFDocument = async (docData,docName) => {
      ...
  }
 
  return(
      <Button className="mr-4" onClick={handleClick}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={pdfCreatingState ? faCog : faFilePdf} title={"Generate PDF report"} className={pdfCreatingState ? "fa-spin" : ""} />
      </Button>
  );

}
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: its not working for me :(
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sync" size={32} style={styles.colorGrey} onPress={onPressSync} className="fa-spin"/>

Comment: @varun I'm no expert and I can't test right now, but maybe if you try importing the icon? `import { sync } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'`. I'm sure you have added the necessary packages to your project? `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome`. Then use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={sync} size={32} style={styles.colorGrey} onPress={onPressSync} className="fa-spin"/>`. idk just a thought

Comment: There's something more going on here.  The icons on this page only spin on a  Mac, but not on Windows when I add `fa-spin`: https://fontawesome.com/icons

Answer (score 4):

I had the same situation with Nextjs and noticed that the proper `<style>` tag for animation was not being generated. So I solved the problem by directly importing it. In my case, Adding `import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"` fixes the issue, and FontAwesome works as intended.

Comment: This solved the issue for me too, also using Next.js.

Comment: I had to add `"use client"` at the top of my component file to get animations to work

Answer (score 1):

In my project I'm using `react-icons/fa` and the answer provided by @Qudusayo worked very well for smooth spinners. If anyone is trying to create a 'pulsed' or 'step' spinner, here's how you can do that:

**CSS:**

```
.icon_pulse {
    animation: circle 1.2s steps(8) infinite;
}

@keyframes circle {
    from {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(450deg);
    }
}
```

**JSX:**

```
<FaSpinner className="icon_pulse" />
```